# Chartist plugin tooltip : Adding the label in the tooltip

Tags: chartist.js

Assuming I have this kind of data for my pie chart and I'm gonna use [GlobeGitter's Chartist Plugin Tooltip](https://github.com/Globegitter/chartist-plugin-tooltip)

```
        var data = {
            labels: ['ra','rb','rc','rd','re','rf'],
            series: [5, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4]
        };
```

How can I add the value of labels in my tooltip? Sample text of tooltip

> ra : 5

Answer (score 2):

Add the script and css to your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/chartist-plugin-tooltip.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chartist-plugin-pointlabels.js" /></script>
```

Then add the plugin into your options like this:

```
new Chartist.Bar('#ct_chart', {
   labels: ['ra','rb','rc','rd','re','rf'],
   series: [5, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4]

   }, { 
   plugins: [
     Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
   ]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
    labels: ['ra', 'rb', 'rc', 'rd', 're', 'rf'],
    series: [[
        { meta: 'ra', value: 5 },
        { meta: 'rb', value: 3 },
        { meta: 'rc', value: 4 },
        { meta: 'rd', value: 1 },
        { meta: 're', value: 6 },
        { meta: 'rf', value: 4 },
    ]], { 
        plugins: [
            Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Think that 'GlobeGitter's Chartist Plugin Tooltip' is not compatible with pie charts, but you can use 'tooltipster' here is an example 
Visit jsbin.com/xojezu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: **GlobeGitter's Chartist Plugin Tooltip** has become **https://github.com/tmmdata/chartist-plugin-tooltip**, and is now compatible with Pie charts and Donut charts:-) As some pull requests are not merged, please think about manually implementing some of them (I recommend 160 and 173). Works great with Pie and Donut.